# Safest way to remove Ubuntu from dual boot PC

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I have a PC with Ubuntu and Windows 7. Now I am intending to remove Ubuntu from there. If I login from Windows and use a Partition tool to delete Ubuntu and reclaim its space, I am afraid it would affect booting because boot menu is GRUB.

How would one take care of the same? I do not have a Windows media because it came installed with the PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple. Ideally you want to back up your system before you do anything, since if you do have issues, this could hose your system. I've personally never had any issues tho

Boot into the windows partition, and use [easybcd](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (there's a free personal use version under 'plans') or [visualbcd](http://www.boyans.net/) to reinstall the windows bootloader (there's native ways too, but this is much easier). Then reboot and check to see that you're not using grub any more. Delete the ubuntu partition, and extend the windows partition and you are set.